Applying Window Film (Gila Heat Control Titanium) to Hurricane Impact Windows?
I am a renter and want to make sure it is safe to install the Gila Heat Control Titanium window film to the inside of my hurricane impact bedroom windows. I was able to get the window info from my landlord - they are these double hung tilt windows linked here -> https://condadowindow.com/product/double-hung-tilt-window/
But she doesn't know which type of glass exactly was installed (either the Vinyl glazed 1/4" thick glass, Safety laminated glass with a 0.030" pvb interlayer, or Structural silicone 5/16” Laminated Impact Glass with a 0.090” PVB interlayer).
Does anyone know if it is safe to apply the film to any of these glass options? I couldn't find a direct answer when researching and got nervous when I saw something about the laminated impact windows being bad candidates for window film.
Thanks for any help! I am meltingggggg

Did the landlord also give you the OK to install film onto the windows?

It shouldn't really matter—you're only applying it to the inside.  If the LL has given the OK, your biggest worry is probably just bubbles.
